# Modify json file using some condition and create new json file in r

Tags: json, r

For the JSON file in this format :

```
{
  "Content": " Some content ",
  "Number": "52",
  "Sub Content": [

{
  "Name": "SC1",
  "Value": "100"
},
{
"Name": "SC2",
"Value": "25"
}
]
}
```

I need to check the value of "Number", it is "52", I have to change value of "SC2" from "25" to "46" using R.

Any help to achieve this.

Comment: What do you have so far? This is not that complicated with jsonlite or RJSONIO.

Comment: I haven't used json file in r before and so not able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using a json handling package.

```
install.packages('rjson',dependencies=TRUE)
```

Next, read your json into a variable. let's say `myjson`

Convert your json into a list:

```
myjsonList = fromJSON(myjson)
```

Make your changes

```
if(myjsonList$Number == 52){
     myjsonList$'Sub Content'[[2]]$Value=25
}
```

And make it a json again.

```
newjson= toJSON(myjsonList)
```