# Importing, editing and saving JSON in a simple way?

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I'm having problems with editing a JSON file and saving the results in a usable form.

My starting point is : [modify-json-file-using-some-condition-and-create-new-json-file-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275877/modify-json-file-using-some-condition-and-create-new-json-file-in-r)

In fact I want to do something even simpler and it still doesn't work! I'm using the jsonlite package.

An equivalent sample would look like this ...

```
$Apples
$Apples$Origin
$Apples$Origin$Id
[1] 2615

$Apples$Origin$season
[1] "Fall"

$Oranges
$Oranges$Origin
$Oranges$Origin$Id
[1] 2615

$Oranges$Origin$airportLabel
[1] "Orange airport"

$Oranges$Shipping
$Oranges$Shipping$ShipperId
[1] 123

$Oranges$Shipping$ShipperLabel
[1] "Brighter Orange"
```

I read the file, make some changes and save the resulting file back to HDD.  Nothing simpler right?

```
json_list = read_json(path = "../documents/dummy.json")

json_list$Apples$Origin$Id = 1234
json_list$Oranges$Origin$Id = 4567
json_list$Oranges$Shipping$ShipperLabel = "Suntan Blue"

json_modified <- toJSON(json_list, pretty = TRUE)

write_json(json_modified, path = "../documents/dummy_new.json")
```

*json_list* appears as character format under the Rstudio file type column.
*json_modified* appears as json format under the Rstudio file type column.

Why this difference?

Now if I run the original file it works but the modified file fails.  The JSON format checks out and I can't see any errors.

The real file is bigger than the example above but the method I've used is the same.

Am I doing something wrong in the way I edit or save the file?

I'm really new to JSON and this is really frustrating!

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This is *close to* but not quite reproducible. Can you provide either or both of: (1) raw contents of your JSON file; (2) `dput(json_list)` and/or `dput(json_modified)`. Thanks!

Comment: Question: do you have the [**`RJSONIO`**](https://rdrr.io/cran/RJSONIO/) package attached as well?  If so, the call to `toJSON()` could be ambiguous: [`jsonlite::toJSON()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/man/fromJSON.html) or [`RJSONIO::toJSON()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/RJSONIO/man/toJSON.html).  That said, **you shouldn't need to use `toJSON()` before calling [`jsonlite::write_json()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/man/read_json.html)**.

Comment: dput(json_list) gives:


list(Apples = list(Origin = list(Id = 2615L, season = "Fall")), 
    Oranges = list(Origin = list(Id = 2615L, airportLabel = "Orange airport"), 
        Shipping = list(ShipperId = 123L, ShipperLabel = "Brighter Orange")))


dput(json_modified) ... without toJSON ... gives: 


list(Apples = list(Origin = list(Id = 1234, season = "Fall")), 
    Oranges = list(Origin = list(Id = 4567, airportLabel = "Orange airport"), 
        Shipping = list(ShipperId = 123L, ShipperLabel = "Suntan")))


If I run toJSON before dput() I escape characters

Comment: RJSONIO package isn't used

Comment: @Greg Removing toJSON() fixes the problem.

Many thanks

Comment: @SteveG Glad to hear it! Thanks for accepting the answer; would you kindly upvote too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of reproducible data, I can diagnose at least one potential problem.

## Background

Within the [**`jsonlite`**](https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/) package, there exist functions that are mutual inverses:

- [`jsonlite::fromJSON()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/man/fromJSON.html) converts from raw text (in JSON format) to R objects.
- [`jsonlite::toJSON()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/man/fromJSON.html) converts from R objects to raw text (in JSON format).

Now this raw text (`txt`) might be

> a JSON string, URL or file

As for [`jsonlite::read_json()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/man/read_json.html) and [`jsonlite::write_json()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/man/read_json.html), they are also a pair of mutual inverses, which are like the former pair

> except [that] they explicitly distinguish between path and literal input, and do not simplify by default.

That is, the latter are simply designed to handle file(path)s rather than strings of raw text.

So `toJSON(fromJSON(txt = ...))` should return unchanged the text passed to `txt`, just as `write_json(read_json(path = ...))` should write a file identical to that passed to `path`.

**In short, `toJSON()` belongs with `fromJSON()`; while `write_json()` belongs with `read_json()`.**

## The Problem

However, **you have added a spurious step** by mingling `toJSON()` with `read_json()` and `write_json()`:

```
json_list = read_json(...)

# ...
json_modified <- toJSON(json_list, ...) # SPURIOUS STEP
# ...

write_json(json_modified, ...)
```

You see, `write_json()` *already* converts "to JSON", so **`toJSON()` is wholly unnecessary**. Indeed, `toJSON()` actually *sabotages* the process, since its *textual* return value is passed on (in `json_modified`) to `write_json()`, which expects (a structure of) *R objects* rather than text.

## The Fix

Once you're done modifying `json_list`, just go straight to writing it:

```
json_list = read_json(path = "../documents/dummy.json")

json_list$Apples$Origin$Id = 1234
# Further modifications...

write_json(json_list, path = "../documents/dummy_new.json", pretty = TRUE)
```